# RotateFlipType wrong values when used in settings

Tags: .net, system.drawing

I'm trying to use System.Drawing.RotateFlipType in my settings file. This screenshot summarizes my problem:

[alt text http://l-2.incito.hr/rotatefliptype.png](http://l-2.incito.hr/rotatefliptype.png)

Each of RotateFlipType values is doubled, and some are missing. If I try to use some of missing values (like Rotate180FlipX, through app.config) - it is simply ignored.

Using VS2008 with SP1, vb.net with framework 3.5 on windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Summary:
//     Specifies the direction of an image's rotation and the axis used to flip
//     the image.
public enum RotateFlipType
{
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies a 180-degree rotation followed by a horizontal and vertical flip.
    Rotate180FlipXY = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies no rotation and no flipping.
    RotateNoneFlipNone = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies a 270-degree rotation followed by a horizontal and vertical flip.
    Rotate270FlipXY = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies a 90-degree rotation without flipping.
    Rotate90FlipNone = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies a 180-degree rotation without flipping.
    Rotate180FlipNone = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies no rotation followed by a horizontal and vertical flip.
    RotateNoneFlipXY = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies a 270-degree rotation without flipping.
    Rotate270FlipNone = 3,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies a 90-degree rotation followed by a horizontal and vertical flip.
    Rotate90FlipXY = 3,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies a 180-degree rotation followed by a vertical flip.
    Rotate180FlipY = 4,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies no rotation followed by a horizontal flip.
    RotateNoneFlipX = 4,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies a 90-degree rotation followed by a horizontal flip.
    Rotate90FlipX = 5,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies a 270-degree rotation followed by a vertical flip.
    Rotate270FlipY = 5,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies no rotation followed by a vertical flip.
    RotateNoneFlipY = 6,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies a 180-degree rotation followed by a horizontal flip.
    Rotate180FlipX = 6,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies a 90-degree rotation followed by a vertical flip.
    Rotate90FlipY = 7,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies a 270-degree rotation followed by a horizontal flip.
    Rotate270FlipX = 7,
}
```

Take a paper and try to flip&rotate it and you'll see that duplicate values are indeed duplicate, ie. they represent the same transformation.  Enum converter obviously goes from 0 to 7, searches enum string and gets FIRST for you.